# What is the current most widely-accepted explanation of gravity?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, spacetime, quantum-gravity, carrier-particles

What do physicists typically say gives gravity the ability to act on a pair of objects?
I am not asking for a description of gravity as a scalar field, but rather what the current accepted theory is on how objects thousands of light years away from each other can exert force on each other?

If the answer involves gravitons, please explain how they could be able to interact over these distances to exert forces on objects.

Comment: This might help - [What is General Relativity?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYq774z4dws)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The current best theory of gravity is Einstein's general theory of relativity, which explains gravity as an effect of the curvature of spacetime by energy, momentum, stress, and pressure. Over the past century many alternative theories have been proposed, and many experiments and observations conducted to test these alternative theories and general relativity, and so far Einstein's theory has passed all challenges and remains the simplest theory which is in accord with all observations.

Having said that, there are reasons to believe that eventually another theory will supplant general relativity (GR). That is because GR is not a quantum theory, and all other aspects of the universe (including the existence of particles and the non-gravitational forces between them) are explained by quantum theories, specifically quantum field theories. Developing a quantum theory of gravity is an active area of research, but testing such theories is very difficult because gravity is a very weak force and quantum gravitational effects are expected to be observed only in extreme situations or at very tiny levels.

Most (but not all) quantum theories of gravity predict the existence of a spin-2 particle called the "graviton", which would be an excitation of the quantum gravitational field in much the same way as the photon is an excitation of the electromagnetic field. Gravitons, like photons, are predicted to be massless and hence able to travel arbitrary distances at the speed of light. Just as the light from a distant star is able to travel vast distances to eventually interact with the rods and cones in your eye, so gravitons would be able to traverse interstellar space to interact with matter. (Technically gravitons would make up gravitational waves, and the force of gravity would be modelled by exchange of virtual gravitons, but in either case there would be no range limit.)

Answer (score 3):

Simply put: the accepted answer (experimentally verified in a variety of different tests) is that gravity is how we experience something called curved spacetime, that matter and energy can curve spacetime, and that the effects of spacetime curvature are propagated at the speed of light across essentially infinite distances- and that it is always attractive and never repulsive.

Spacetime curvature can be mapped across space as if it were a field. The fundamental excitation of that field is a thing called a graviton, which serves as the force-carrier for that field.

The idea of the graviton was invented to furnish a mechanism for the propagation of spacetime curvature effects that would comport with quantum field theory and could possibly be included in an extension of the standard model of particle physics. There is no evidence for its physical existence, so at present it is a mathematical abstraction. To be always attractive, it must be spin 2 and to have infinite range it must be massless, and if massless, it propagates at the velocity of light, c.